# Can't type Korean any more after 14.10 upgrade

Tags: keyboard-layout, 14.10, korean

Basically what the title says. I'm using ibus for the keyboard layout and have ibus-hangul (re-)installed. Everything worked fine until I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.10. I can still switch to Korean, as can be seen in the picture. Yet the letters that Ubuntu lets me type in Korean-mode are not Hangul as you can see, since I wrote this entirely in Korean-language-mode. So how do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Hangul mode was turned off by default despite entering the Hangul language mode.

[image]

You can either click on *Hangul mode* to turn it on or turn it on by default by going to *Setup->Start in hangul mode*.

[image]

After you have restarted, Hangul mode will be turned on by default and you will be able to type Korean without having to manually click *Hangul mode* every time.

[image]